# Alguien que sepa condicionales (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero decirle a la consola que si mi score esta entre 195 y 198 me diga estas muy cerca. ¿Cómo lo hago? ¿Qué tengo hecho mal?

```js
var score = 155;
var record = 200;

if(score<record){
    console.log("que malo eres tio");
} else if (score==record){
    console.log("casi lo logras");
} else {
    console.log("Lo superaste, eres el puto amo");
}
```

Comment: Por cierto busca los operadores lógicos

Comment: Primero tendrías que cambiar la primera condicional, por ejemplo: `if(score<record && 195>score)`, luego agregar `else if(195<=score && score<=199){console.log("estás muy cerca");}`. En tu caso, como quieres que sea 198 el límite superior, sería `195<=score && score<=198`.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo haría usando operadores lógicos.
El doble **"&&"** es un **"Y lógico"**, vamos como en las tablas **"lógicas de verdad"** de matemática en este caso pues **"conjución"** (https://logicautem.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/tablas-de-verdad.jpg), en el ejemplo que esta más abajo leerías lo que se encuentra dentro de los paréntesis del **if** como " **si** score **es mayor o igual que** 195 **y** score **es mayor o igual que** 198 entonces se ejecuta lo que esta dentro del parentesis".

```js
// si mi score esta entre 195 y 198 me diga estas muy cerca
let score = 155;

if(score >= 195 && score <= 198){
  console.log("Estas muy cerca");
 }
```

espero haberte ayudado, saludos!!

Comment: Si el OP esta aprendiendo entonces mas que mandarle saludos, explicale tu código y para que sirven los `&&`

Comment: Tienes razón, ya lo edite.